# Python: Define a variable inside a "lambda"

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, variables, lambda

So, I tried to search here and couldn't find any solution to that problem: I need to define a variable inside a "lambda".

I have that piece of code:

```
def z(t,s):exec("t=s")
r = type('', (), {
    '__init__': lambda t,*s: z("t.c",s),
    's': lambda t: (lambda t,*s: [t[::-1] for t in s])(*t.c),
    'l': lambda t: (lambda t,*s: list(s[::-1]))(*t.c),
    'd': lambda t: t.c
})

w = ["APPLE", "BEACH", "CITRUS"]
print r(*w).s()
print r(*w).l()
print r(*w).d()
```

Nothing works as it should work... Also when I call the function "d", it returns me this error:

```
AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'c'
```

When it should return a tuple, something like:

```
('ALPHA', 'BRAVO', 'CHARLIE')
```

**EDIT: Thanks guys, it works now, and is even smaller:**

```
r=type('',(),{'__init__':lambda t,*s:setattr(t,'c',s),'s':lambda t:[t[::-1] for t in t.c],'l':lambda t:list(t.c[::-1]),'d':lambda t:t.c})
```

Comment: Why the heck are you doing this instead of just using a `class` statement? And are you aware that `def` can do literally anything `lambda` can?

Comment: Because it's a one-liner:
`def z(t,s):exec("t=s");r=type('',(),{'c':'','__init__':lambda t,*s:z(t.c,s),'s':lambda t:(lambda t,*s:[t[::-1] for t in s])(*t.c),'l':lambda t:(lambda t,*s:list(s[::-1]))(*t.c),'d':lambda t:t.c})`

Comment: "Because it's a one-liner" isn't a good reason to do things, especially when your one-liner doesn't fit on a line anyway.

Comment: It does fit on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to set an attribute: (If you want something like `self.c = s`)

```
'__init__': lambda t,*s: setattr(t, 'c', s),
```

---

```
>>> r = type('', (), {
...     '__init__': lambda t,*s: setattr(t, 'c', s),
...     's': lambda t: (lambda t,*s: [t[::-1] for t in s])(*t.c),
...     'l': lambda t: (lambda t,*s: list(s[::-1]))(*t.c),
...     'd': lambda t: t.c
... })
>>>
>>> w = ["APPLE", "BEACH", "CITRUS"]
>>> print r(*w).s()
['HCAEB', 'SURTIC']
>>> print r(*w).l()
['CITRUS', 'BEACH']
>>> print r(*w).d()
('APPLE', 'BEACH', 'CITRUS')
```

Comment: @WilliamFernandes, Inner lambdas in `s` and `l` is redundant:  `'s': lambda t: [t[::-1] for t in t.c[1:]]`  ,  `'l': lambda t: list(t.c[1:][::-1])`

Comment: @WilliamFernandes, Maybe you wanted this? `'s': lambda t: [t[::-1] for t in t.c], 'l': lambda t: list(t.c[::-1]),`

Comment: @WilliamFernandes, As others commented, avoid one-liner. It's hard to understand; hard to maintain.